# Returning stream of futures from function

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function which reads a response from a server and returns a stream of futures which when awaited should return a type which implements the tokio `AsyncRead` trait:

```rust
pub async fn connect_peers(url: &str) -> impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = impl AsyncRead> {
    let response = reqwest::get(url).await.unwrap().bytes().await.unwrap();
    let peers: &[u8] = // parse response ...

    peers.array_chunks().map(|x: &[u8; 6]| {
        let (&ip, port) = x.split_array_ref::<4>();
        let addr = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::from(ip), BigEndian::read_u16(port));
        tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(addr)
    }).collect()
}
```

However, I get the following compile error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `impl Stream<Item = impl tokio::io::AsyncRead>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
    --> src/lib.rs:350:12
     |
350  |         }).collect()
     |            ^^^^^^^ value of type `impl Stream<Item = impl tokio::io::AsyncRead>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>>` is not implemented for `impl Stream<Item = impl tokio::io::AsyncRead>`
```

I am not sure how to create a `futures::stream::Stream` from the iterator returned by `peers.array_chunks().map(|x: &[u8; 6]| { ... })`.

This [blog post](https://gendignoux.com/blog/2021/04/01/rust-async-streams-futures-part1.html#primer-creating-a-stream-of-pages) show that something like this is possible:

```
fn get_pages_futures() -> impl Stream<Item = impl Future<Output = Vec<usize>>> {
    stream::iter(0..).map(|i| get_page(i))
}
```

where `get_page` is an async function returning `Vec<usize>`. But I am not sure how this would translate to my use case.

I have tried the following return type signature (adding the future as output):

```rust
impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = impl futures::Future<Output = impl AsyncRead>>
```

which gives the following compile error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `impl Stream<Item = impl futures::Future<Output = impl tokio::io::AsyncRead>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>`
    --> src/lib.rs:350:12
     |
350  |         }).collect()
     |            ^^^^^^^ value of type `impl Stream<Item = impl futures::Future<Output = impl tokio::io::AsyncRead>>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>>` is not implemented for `impl Stream<Item = impl futures::Future<Output = impl tokio::io::AsyncRead>>`
```

How do I return an asynchronous stream from the `connect_peers` function?

Comment: Please try to provide a stand-alone example that reproduces your issue. I think I've done it after some tinkering: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9553e5b3eb0c1f0e301ab6d6656c3258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `stream::iter()` is on the right track - it converts an iterator to a stream. Since you already have an iterator, you need to replace `xxx.collect()` with `stream::iter(xxx)`:

```
futures::stream::iter(peers.array_chunks().map(|x: &[u8; 6]| {
    let (&ip, port) = x.split_array_ref::<4>();
    let addr = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::from(ip), BigEndian::read_u16(port));
    tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(addr)
}))
```

However, that results in an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<tokio::net::TcpStream, std::io::Error>>: tokio::io::AsyncRead` is not satisfied
```

If you take a more careful look at the code, the error makes sense: we promised to return a stream of something that implements `AsyncRead` (such as `TcpStream`), but `connect()` doesn't return a `TcpStream`, it returns a future that will, once it completes, return a `TcpStream`.

To fix this, you need to turn your stream that returns futures into a stream that returns `TcpStreams` - something like:

```
futures::stream::iter(peers.array_chunks().map(|x: &[u8; 6]| {
    // ...
    tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(addr)
}))
.map(|connect| async { connect.await.unwrap() })
```

However `StreamExt::map()` takes an ordinary closure, and we need an async version. The async equivalent of `map()` is, somewhat surprisingly called [`then()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.then), and if we change `map()` to `then()`, the code compiles:

```
pub async fn connect_peers(url: &str) -> impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = impl AsyncRead> {
    let response = reqwest::get(url).await.unwrap().bytes().await.unwrap();
    let peers: &[u8] = b"foo";

    futures::stream::iter(peers.array_chunks().map(|x: &[u8; 6]| {
        let (&ip, port) = x.split_array_ref::<4>();
        let addr = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::from(ip), BigEndian::read_u16(port));
        tokio::net::TcpStream::connect(addr)
    }))
    .then(|connect| async { connect.await.unwrap() })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=282ede3dc3b298c7e52af3355c005752)

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot figure how to use response from the request with the future stream. [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5d0e930358e58194caa59682028e80d6)

Comment: @Kevin That's because `array_chunks()` is a method on slice, so it borrows from `response`. You can simply switch to a more mundane method of iterating over array chunks, such as with indexes: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7ad49ac54a482704742c57589f324db